# Почему между одиночным определением и причастным оборотом не ставится запятая?

Tags: определения

Почему между одиночным определением и причастным оборотом не ставится запятая в следующих примерах?

Чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал.

Comment: Вот правило: Однородные и неоднородные определения (пункт 7). https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/48854/13/Rozental%27_-_Spravochnik_po_russkomu_yazyku._Punktuaciya.html

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова лучше давайте ответы в ответах.

Answer (score 1):

Первые два примера зачем-то написаны "берёзовым весёлым языком", от него (как и от излишнего теоретизирования с раздачей определений) и возникает недоумение. Измените порядок слов ("появившиеся чёрные пятна" и "потёртый заячий воротник"), и запятые ставить расхочется уже на интуитивном уровне, хотя можно и в "неоднородных определениях" порыться.

Comment: А что нам дает изменение порядка слов? Вот пример из указанного выше правила (с запятой): _твёрдый, плохо выбритый подбородок (ср. при другом порядке слов: плохо выбритый твёрдый подбородок)._ Сначала есть запятая, а после перестановки — нет. Так в чем разница?

Comment: Здесь "твёрдый" - не разновидность подбородка (они сами по себе не делятся на твёрдые и нетвёрдые), за этим эпитетом следует уточнение (почему он кажется твёрдым) - оправдание "твёрдости" можно поискать в синонимичности "плохой выбритости". Попытка же после перестановки трактовать определения как неоднородные выглядит неубедительно: запятая не должна исчезнуть, хотя при обратном порядке слов выражение становится столь же неуклюжим, как в наших двух примерах.

Comment: Я совершенно ничего не трактую — просто привожу примеры из правила Розенталя и пытаюсь понять, для чего Вы "понапереставляли" определения.

Comment: Я переставил слова в том порядке, в котором естественно воспринимается их смысл. Ведь на смысле и держится грамматическая классификация определений как однородных или неоднородных. В примере из Розенталя (да, ему приходилось цитировать и сомнительных авторов) "обратная" перестановка делает выражение настолько корявым, что оно не воспринимается ни с запятой, ни без неё. Я говорил не о Вашей трактовке, а о предложенной в том примере перестановке с убиранием запятой (с такой трактовкой не могу согласиться).